# Need to pass `Client-Id` header parameter from c# code using HttpClient() to call a Rest API Post method

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have a Curl in Swagger Resp Api as `curl -X POST "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/11" -H  "accept: application/xml" -H  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H  "Client-Id: example.demo.com" -d "name=James&status=K"` How can I pass the `Client-Id` from c# code using HttpClient() request header

Comment: I had tried httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Client-Id", "example.demo.com") but it didn't work.

Comment: Can we monitor the API calls using fiddler

Comment: Code you showed should work. Please add all code what you have for this request I'll try to help you.